# How do I make scalar's medium face in this bespoke document clas?

Tags: fonts, typefaces

There is a bespoke document class which can be found here:

http://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?journalCode=rquf20&page=instructions

See section 2 style guidelines.

They also state that scalar's should be displayed as medium face sloping serif.

http://www.tandf.co.uk/journals/authors/style/Mathematical-Scripts.pdf

See the 6th bullet point.

Using the template supplied (please use this template and all the accompanying files when replicating this). The y(\tau) appears as sloping serif in the equation but it seems to my eyes that the y(\tau) in the text seems to be in the same regular face as the equation version?

[image]

How can I change this so that the equation version is in medium face?

```
\documentclass{rQUF2e}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\begin{document}

 y(\tau)

\begin{equation}
    y(\tau) = \beta1 + \beta2 \left( \frac{1-e^{-\lambda \tau} }{\lambda \tau} \right)+\beta3 \left( \frac{1-e^{-\lambda \tau}}{\lambda \tau}-e^{-\lambda \tau} \right) 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164816/how-to-use-semibold-italic-cmbright-for-bold-math-symbols

Comment: Hi there although the cmbright package does indeed provide medium face fonts it is only for the 'Computer Modern Bright' fonts which are sans-serif fonts. http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cmbright. However I need to do the same thing for serif fonts.

Comment: `y(\tau)` generates an error message so any output you get is arbitrary, `\tau` is a math mode command, the markup has to be `$ y(\tau)$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing for you to do here, it just means for variables denoting scalar values just use the default font not `\mathbf` etc.

`y(\tau)` generates an error message so any output you get is arbitrary, `\tau` is a math mode command, the markup has to be `$ y(\tau)$`